# Retrieve post_title from WordPress object

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to retrieve the Post Title from a WordPress object.

Here is a `var_dump` resulting from the **WP_Query**:

> object(WP_Query)#4305 (49) { ["query"]=> array(2) { ["post_type"]=>
>   string(5) "cases" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(-1) } ["query_vars"]=>
>   array(64) { ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases" ["posts_per_page"]=>
>   int(-1) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0)
>   ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["static"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0)
>   ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0)
>   ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["meta_key"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["embed"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=>
>   array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0)
>   { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_name__in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=>
>   bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=>
>   bool(true) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true)
>   ["lazy_load_term_meta"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=>
>   bool(true) ["nopaging"]=> bool(true) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2)
>   "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" }
>   ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#4307 (6) { ["queries"]=> array(0)
>   { } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" ["table_aliases":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["queried_terms"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_table"]=>
>   string(8) "wp_posts" ["primary_id_column"]=> string(2) "ID" }
>   ["meta_query"]=> object(WP_Meta_Query)#4303 (9) { ["queries"]=>
>   array(0) { } ["relation"]=> NULL ["meta_table"]=> NULL
>   ["meta_id_column"]=> NULL ["primary_table"]=> NULL
>   ["primary_id_column"]=> NULL ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) {
>   } ["clauses":protected]=> array(0) { } ["has_or_relation":protected]=>
>   bool(false) } ["date_query"]=> bool(false) ["request"]=> string(259)
>   "SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type =
>   'cases' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status
>   = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_author = 44 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC " ["posts"]=> array(42) { [0]=> object(WP_Post)#4270 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(19269)
>   ["post_author"]=> string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2018-10-02
>   10:46:05" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-10-02 08:46:05"
>   ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(17) "Terberg -
>   ANNAbel" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7)
>   "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=>
>   string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=>
>   string(7) "annabel" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0)
>   "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 12:37:10"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:37:10"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19269"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [1]=> object(WP_Post)#4269 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(19161) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-09-28 15:46:05" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-09-28 13:46:05" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(19) "De Voordelige Groep" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(19) "de-voordelige-groep"
>   ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 12:28:00"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:28:00"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19161"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [2]=> object(WP_Post)#4268 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(19163) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-09-28 15:42:12" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-09-28 13:42:12" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(16) "Global Factories" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(16) "global-factories"
>   ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 12:41:57"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:41:57"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19163"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [3]=> object(WP_Post)#4267 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(19167) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-09-21 14:58:50" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-09-21 12:58:50" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(24) "Warmteservice Groep B.V." ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(13) "warmteservice" ["to_ping"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-11-15 12:00:56" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15
>   11:00:56" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=>
>   int(0) ["guid"]=> string(48)
>   "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19167" ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
>   ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [4]=>
>   object(WP_Post)#4266 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(19157) ["post_author"]=>
>   string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2018-09-21 11:26:12"
>   ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-09-21 09:26:12"
>   ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(9) "Blauwtulp"
>   ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish"
>   ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(11)
>   "blauwtulp-2" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 12:46:48"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:46:48"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19157"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [5]=> object(WP_Post)#4265 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(19154) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-09-21 11:15:52" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-09-21 09:15:52" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(22) "AO Smith International" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(8) "ao-smith" ["to_ping"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-11-15 12:39:59" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15
>   11:39:59" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=>
>   int(0) ["guid"]=> string(48)
>   "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19154" ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
>   ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [6]=>
>   object(WP_Post)#4264 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(19103) ["post_author"]=>
>   string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2018-09-12 12:13:53"
>   ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-09-12 10:13:53"
>   ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(10)
>   "FixFast.de" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=>
>   string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed"
>   ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_name"]=> string(10) "fixfast-de" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15
>   12:23:55" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:23:55"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19103"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [7]=> object(WP_Post)#4263 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(19072) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-09-05 13:05:27" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-09-05 11:05:27" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(8) "Shopware" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=>
>   string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed"
>   ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_name"]=> string(8) "shopware" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-09-05
>   13:30:52" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-09-05 11:30:52"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19072"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [8]=> object(WP_Post)#4262 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(18910) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-07-12 14:16:15" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-07-12 12:16:15" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(11) "Burger King" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(13) "burger-king-2" ["to_ping"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-11-15 11:59:50" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15
>   10:59:50" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=>
>   int(0) ["guid"]=> string(48)
>   "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18910" ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
>   ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [9]=>
>   object(WP_Post)#4261 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(18907) ["post_author"]=>
>   string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2018-07-12 13:50:43"
>   ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-07-12 11:50:43"
>   ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(14) "Ideal
>   Standard" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7)
>   "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=>
>   string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=>
>   string(14) "ideal-standard" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 12:06:02"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:06:02"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18907"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [10]=> object(WP_Post)#4260 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(18760) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-07-11 12:29:18" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-07-11 10:29:18" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(18) "Thomas Stofzuigers" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(20) "thomas-stofzuigers-2"
>   ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 12:44:26"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:44:26"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18760"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [11]=> object(WP_Post)#4259 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(18858) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-07-11 12:10:23" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-07-11 10:10:23" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(22) "Waaijenberg Mobiliteit" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(22) "waaijenberg-mobiliteit"
>   ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 12:24:50"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:24:50"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18858"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [12]=> object(WP_Post)#4258 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(18852) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-07-11 10:04:06" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-07-11 08:04:06" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(20) "Buiskoppelingshop.nl" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(22) "buiskoppelingshop-nl-2"
>   ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 12:26:55"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-11-15 11:26:55"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18852"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [13]=> object(WP_Post)#4257 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(18655) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-05-24 13:10:32" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-05-24 11:10:32" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(8) "SprayPay" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=>
>   string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed"
>   ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_name"]=> string(8) "spraypay" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-05-24
>   13:13:14" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-05-24 11:13:14"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18655"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [14]=> object(WP_Post)#4256 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(18653) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-05-24 12:17:25" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-05-24 10:17:25" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(5) "Sooqr" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=>
>   string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed"
>   ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_name"]=> string(5) "sooqr" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-05-24
>   12:17:25" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-05-24 10:17:25"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18653"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [15]=> object(WP_Post)#4255 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(18650) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-05-24 11:37:51" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-05-24 09:37:51" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(6) "Pay.nl" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=>
>   string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed"
>   ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_name"]=> string(6) "pay-nl" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-05-24
>   11:43:57" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-05-24 09:43:57"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18650"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [16]=> object(WP_Post)#4254 (24) {
>   ["ID"]=> int(18645) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-05-23 16:46:32" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-05-23 14:46:32" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(11) "Hellodialog" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(11) "hellodialog" ["to_ping"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-05-30 15:26:13" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-05-30
>   13:26:13" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=>
>   int(0) ["guid"]=> string(48)
>   "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18645" ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
>   ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }
>   [17]=> object(WP_Post)#4253 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(18643)
>   ["post_author"]=> string(1) "3" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2018-05-23
>   16:32:09" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-05-23 14:32:09"
>   ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(16) "Feedback
>   Company" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7)
>   "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=>
>   string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=>
>   string(16) "feedback-company" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-05-23 16:34:46"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-05-23 14:34:46"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=18643"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"

I am trying to get the `post_title`. This is what I have so far:

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'cases',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
                $case_title = get_field('post_title');
                echo $case_title;

                var_dump($the_query);
    ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;?>
```

But it is not retrieving the title.

What should I be doing to retrieve the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo the Title you can do this `<?php the_title(); ?>` and to put the title in a var you can do this `$title = get_the_title();`

for more information: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

```
<?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'cases',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
                $case_title = get_the_title();
                echo $case_title;
                // or
                echo the_title();

                var_dump($the_query);
    ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is the standard wordpress way to get a title. The object is derived from a Custom Post Type. I am trying to extract, for example, post_title.

Comment: I Thought maybe you got them mixed up. If it is a custom post type `get_field()` should work. You can try `echo the_field();`.

Comment: @mdarmanin `get_the_title()` should retrieve the CPT post title as showing in the `var_dump`. See excerpt of 1st post object:
[0]=> object(WP_Post)#4270 (24) {
 ["ID"]=> int(19269)
 ["post_author"]=> string(1) "2"
 ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2018-10-02 10:46:05"
 ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-10-02 08:46:05"
 ["post_content"]=> string(0) ""
 **["post_title"]=> string(17) "Terberg - ANNAbel"**
 ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish"
 ["post_name"]=> string(7) "annabel"
 ["guid"]=> string(48) "https://www.zeo.nl/?post_type=cases&p=19269"
 ["post_type"]=> string(5) "cases"
}

Comment: Is there any fast way to sort such an object in a more orderly fashion like in JS?

Comment: Okay never mind, doing a var_dump and checking DOM display orderly